C++ no conversion from const char [n] to const char *?
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class MyString
{
  public:
  MyString() {
    std::cout << "1";
  }
  explicit MyString(const char *str) {
    std::cout << "2";
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyString str1 = MyString("abcde");
  MyString str2("abcde");
  MyString str3 = "abcde";

  return 0;
}

str1 and str2 are created just fine, printing out 2. But when I run it with str3 I get the following error message:
Compilation failed due to following error(s).main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:19: error: conversion from ‘const char [6]’ to non-scalar type ‘MyString’ requested
19 |   MyString str3 = "abcde";

Aren't all 3 lines supposed to call the second constructor, because of RVO? Or is it because I'm using a non-RVO compiler? I tried it both on CMake and gcc and both have the same error message.
I tried creating an operator= and still got the same error, so it clearly isn't from RVO:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class MyString
{
  public:
  MyString() {
    std::cout << "1";
  }
  explicit MyString(const char *str) {
    std::cout << "2";
  }
  MyString& operator=(const char *str) {
    std::cout << "3";
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyString str1 = MyString("abcde");
  MyString str2("abcde");
  MyString str3 = "abcde";

  return 0;
}

I searched around for quite a bit, but couldn't find an answer.

The constructor is explicit so will not be used for implicit conversion.

Optimizations like RVO never plays a role in deciding whether a program is well-formed or not, and assignment operator is completely irrelevant here.

Also, despite using the = symbol, there is no assignment here, only initialization. So the assignment operator is not considered.

There are a couple of very good videos on YouTube explaining the nightmare of initialization in C++. My favorite is C++ on Sea 2019 – Timur Doumler – "Initialisation in modern C++ ", but other is almost as good: CppCon 2018 – Nicolai Josuttis – "The Nightmare of Initialization in C++”.

@WeijunZhou well as far as I know RVO is used to optimize such things as instead of calling a constructor and creating an object and then copying it with the op= it just calls the constructor and constructs do object, without any copying when writing things such as 'A a = A(5)'. So I thought the particular compiler doesn't have RVO, so I tried it out just so I can check, but as I wrote that wasn't the problem. But I guess this is just one compiler case, that I've learned I do know it's quite compiler dependent.

@tbxfreeware I'll check them out, since I'm studying this topic right now, I do know most of the things are compiler dependent, but thank you very much for those!

@BoP thanks, that does fix the issue! I'll look more into explicit since I only knew it can be used so you can't call functons that take an object with something from a one-parameter constructor, but I certainly didn't know this was also one of their use cases (or I guess anti-use cases). Thanks a lot!

What I meant is that, optimizations are applied in a later stage and is implementation detail. Even the compiler decides to omit a constructor call as part of the optimization, the constructor call itself still need to be well formed, so you shouldn't consider optimizations at all when you want to know whether some C++ program is well-formed or not. And no, RVO is not related to operator=. You may be thinking of copy constructor. That may have something to do with RVO. But assignment operator is never relevant. A a=A(5) does not invoke the assignment operator even there's a =.

"copying it with the op=" seems to be where you're confused. copying and op= are actually mutually exclusive. If you copy an object, op= is irrelevant. op= is only relevant when you already have a complete object and you're overwriting it, which is not the case in RVO. In particular, A a=f() does not construct an A, and then call op= with f(). It copy initializes a from f(), which involves the copy constructor, not op=, and that copy-constructor call can be omitted by RVO.

MyString str3 = "abcde"; performs copy initialization, which doesn't work with explicit constructors. More formally:

[...] if T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

Here T is a class type (MyString) and other is not of a class type (const char[6]), and there is no user-defined conversion sequence because one cannot contain explicit constructors.
